# Applescript to print Word documents

Tags: macos, ms-word, printing, applescript, osx-leopard

Is there a way to print all of the Microsoft Word documents (.doc) in a folder using AppleScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, since I don't have my Mac at work, but you get the idea...

```
tell application "Finder"
try
set the source_folder to choose folder with prompt ¬
"Pick a folder containing the documents to process:"
set these_files to every file of the source_folder
repeat with 
tell application "Microsoft Word"
repeat with doc in these_files
print-out doc
end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the source_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Pick the folder containing the documents to process:")
    set these_documents to (every item of the source_folder whose name extension is "doc") as list
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_documents
        set this_item to item i of these_documents
        print this_item
    end repeat
end tell
```